# What's the point of XXX in df.column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I'd like to know if a number is in my `pd.Dataframe` column.

I'd do:

```
999 in test.ind
Out[29]: 
True
```

However, that's odd, given that

```
test.ind.max()
Out[28]: 
932
```

and indeed,

```
(999 == test.ind).sum()
Out[30]: 
0
```

The column is of type `dtype('int64')`. Now, clearly the `x in series` expression  didn't work as I expected. However, is there some other point of this?

**What does `xx in pd.Series` evaluate to?**

Answer (score 4):

it's evaluates whether 999 is in your Series index, the `__contains__ operator` which is what is called when you call `in` tests for the value in the index, not for whether the value is in the values, for that you can use `isin` or `==`:

```
In [6]:
s = pd.Series(np.arange(5), index=list('abcde'))
s

Out[6]:
a    0
b    1
c    2
d    3
e    4
dtype: int32

In [7]:
'c' in s

Out[7]:
True

In [8]:
s.isin([2])

Out[8]:
a    False
b    False
c     True
d    False
e    False
dtype: bool
```

it's implemented like so:

```
def __contains__(self, item):
    return item in self.items
```

see: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/internals.py#L3358

and the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series-is-dict-like)

thanks @chrisb

Comment: See also docs here - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series-is-dict-like